# Link to a <div> on an other page and is hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I'd like to link a button to a div on an other page. But this div is hide because it's part of a sub-nav.
My sub-nav in this page is made of div fading in and out on click.

So here is my script

```
$("#tab2, #tab3, #tab4, #tab5, #tab6").hide();
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Select first tab
    $('.tab-pane').fadeOut(200).promise().done(function(){
        $(href).fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

Here is my sub-nav

```
<div id="menu_secondaire">
<ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1" class="scroll">coiffure</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" class="scroll">bien-être</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" class="scroll">esthétique</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" class="scroll">lumière pulsée</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#tab5" class="scroll">lpg</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#tab6" class="scroll">fitness</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here are the divs

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">Content</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">Content</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">Content</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab-pane">Content</div>
```

How can i show the div tab3 for exemple by default when i come from an other page?
Hope someone'll understand me and thx for your help.

Comment: Do you mean, if someone comes from a specific URL, the hidden `div` will be displayed?

Comment: You could look at the page address using `location.href` and figuring out which tab is listed at the end of the address bar, then adding a `.show` class or something to that tab.

Comment: can you please provide jsFiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cNjyC/

Comment: I mean if you're on the homepage an click a specific button, it takes you to a specific div and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use `:target` css selector for current div and `div:not(:target)` selector for other dives for demo copy below codes in [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target) and submit code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.tab:target
{
border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
background-color: #e5eecc;
visibility:visible 
/*curent div css style*/
}
.tab:not(:target)
{
border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
visibility:hidden
/*other div css style*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p><a href="#news1">Jump to New content 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#news2">Jump to New content 2</a></p>

<p>Click on the links above and the :target selector highlight the current active HTML anchor.</p>

<p class="tab" id="news1"><b>New content 1...</b></p>
<p  class="tab" id="news2"><b>New content 2...</b></p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :target selector.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

you can target from other page. use [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for add delay ,duration and easing mode in css3

Comment: My question was how to show a hidden div directly when you come from another page.

Comment: Here is the thing i'll try to be precise.
I have on the "services" page a subnav wich display a div on click, so all the divs are hidden except one: the div number one.
I want, when a click my link on the "homepage", the arrive on the "services" page and display the div number 3.

Comment: according my solution you should link any subnav in homepage to services divs:                                                      <li><a href="services.html#tab1" class="scroll">coiffure</a> |</li>